# Will wind turbine slow tie to grid tie connection?

Tags: power

If I have wind turbine that produce 10kwatt at 5000rpm with no load, however if I connected that to grid tie inverter and feed the power back to utility grid, will my wind turbine output slow down or speed reduced since its connected to utility grid?

Comment: If you have no load on your turbine, it will overspeed and self-destruct...

Comment: "produce 10kwatt at 5000rpm with no load" Physically impossible.

Comment: It will certainly slow down under load. But the grid tie inverter means there will be no relationship between its own speed and the grid frequency, if that was what you were really asking.

Answer (score 2):

> I have wind turbine that produce 10kwatt at 5000rpm with no load

A wind turbine (or any other generator) cannot produce any useful output power with no load. That makes no sense.

Under load conditions, yes your wind turbine will slow down. This is inevitable.

Comment: inevitable as in "there is no free lunch". There is a price for everything.